# I dont know how to add column "RICHNESS" in the dataframe, also with its data

Tags: r

```
menhinick <- function(x) {
     sum(x>0)/sqrt(sum(x))
}
ddply(df,~Newcode,function(x) {
     data.frame(RICHNESS=menhinick(x[-1]))
})

   Newcode  RICHNESS
1     BL01 1.4508215
2     BL02 1.4050583
3     BL03 1.5321132
4     BL04 1.4142136
5     BL05 0.6479552
6     BL06 1.2880334
7     BL07 0.2820650
8     BL08 1.0684120
9     BL09 0.3252526
10    BL10 0.7363117
11    BL11 1.8349137
12    BL12 1.2174252
13    BL13 1.0563106
14    BL14 1.6669913
15    BL15 1.6175783
16    BL16 1.3056432
17    BL17 1.6294405
18    BL18 0.9885727
```

The vector `Newcode` is already here. But I couldn't find `RICHNESS`. 
Please teach me how to fix it.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Just assign the output of `ddply` to `df`? `df <- ddply(df,~Newcode,function(x) {
     data.frame(RICHNESS=menhinick(x[-1]))
})`

Comment: Now it works well. It takes me 3 days to search the solution.hic

Comment: In general, R functions do not save any operation you perform, unless you explicitly assign it to an object, the same one, or a new one, using `<-`

Comment: I have one more question, please help me fix it.

Comment: I already can draw that list, but now I want to change the "Newcode"by another code list. So I used the code like this: barplot(df$RICHNESS,main = ".....",names.arg = c("BT5","BT4","BT26","BT45","BT7","BT8","BT50","BT14","BT15","BT11","BT16","BT17","BT48","BT34","BT37","BT39","BT52","BT61"), xlab = "Location",ylab = "RICHNESS",ylim = c(0,1),xlim=c(0,20),col = "darkgreen"). It also worked well but the X-axis just appear some names of that list. I didnt know how to make it appear fully although its order is right.  Many thanks in advance!!!!